# Remove sortable icon from PrimeReact datatable header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I used PrimeReact to create a datatable with sortable columns. I imported primeflex for conditional color on some of the cells, but now I am getting these big arrow icons on all my sortable columns and I want to remove them.

Here is a screenshot of the icon I am seeing:
[columns screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CDHS.png)

How do I remove the arrow icons on all columns while still maintaining sortable functionality?

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML of one of those headers?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just set `display:none` on the icons like this CSS

```css
body .p-datatable .p-sortable-column .p-sortable-column-icon {
    display: none;
}
```